# Invalid column name when performing update

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have been trying to update data to database however i met this problem.I tried deleting the table and creating a new table yet the problem still persist.Below are the codes.Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
public int UpdateNOK(string wardClass, DateTime admissionDT, string nokFName, string nokLName, string nokNRIC, DateTime nokDOB, string nokGender, string nokNationality, string nokRelationship, int nokContactH, int nokContactHP, string nokEmail, string nokAddr1, string nokAddr2, string nokState, int nokZIP, string nokCountry, DateTime dischargeDT, string patientNRIC)
    {
        StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
        int result = 0;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlStr.AppendLine("Update patientAdmission");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("SET wardClass = @parawardClass,admissionDT = @paraadmissonDT, nokFName = @parapatientNokFname, nokLName = @parapatientNokLname,nokNRIC = @parapatientNokNRIC,  nokDOB = @parapatientNOKDOB, nokGender = @parapatientNokGender, nokNationality = @parapatientNokNationality,");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("nokRelationship = @parapatientNokRelationship,nokContactH = @parapatientNokContactH,nokContactHP =  @parapatientNokContactHP, nokEmail = @parapatientNokEmail, nokAddr1 = @parapatientNokAddr1,nokAddr2 = @parapatientNokAddr2,nokState = @parapatientNokState, nokZIP = @parapatientNokZIP,");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("nokCountry = @parapatientNokCountry, dischargeDT = @paradischargeDateTime");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("WHERE patientNRIC = @parapatientNRIC");

        try
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myConn);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parawardClass", wardClass);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraadmissonDT", admissionDT);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokFname", nokFName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokLname", nokLName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokNRIC", nokNRIC);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNOKDOB", nokDOB);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokGender", nokGender);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokNationality", nokNationality);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokRelationship", nokRelationship);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokContactH", nokContactH);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokContactHP", nokContactHP);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokEmail", nokEmail);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokAddr1", nokAddr1);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokAddr2", nokAddr2);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokState", nokState);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokZIP", nokZIP);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokCountry", nokCountry);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paradischargeDateTime", dischargeDT);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNRIC", patientNRIC);


            myConn.Open();
            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myConn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logManager log = new logManager();
            log.addLog("patientNOKDAO.UpdateNOK", sqlStr.ToString(), ex);

        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check table definition (`sp_help`) against your used columns in the table `patientAdmission`:

```
wardClass 
admissionDT 
nokFName 
nokLName 
nokNRIC 
nokDOB 
nokGender 
nokNationality 
nokRelationship 
nokContactH 
nokContactHP 
nokEmail 
nokAddr1 
nokAddr2 
nokState 
nokZIP 
nokCountry 
dischargeDT 
patientNRIC
```

If database default collation is a case-sensitive one, column names above must be exactly as defined in the table (case cannot be different).

One way to find the problem faster is to run SQL profiler and see the exact query against the database. Copy-paste it from there and run it into an Management Studio (SSMS) query file (use `BEGIN TRAN` .. `ROLLBACK` to ensure that nothing will actually be changed when you make it work). SSMS will try to indicate the exact column with the problem when clicking on the error.

Comment: seems like the problem is that i need to declare scaler variable at wardClass

Comment: Oh, that seems like another issue (not related to the title). Glad that you found the root cause.

Comment: Now i am trying to resolve it by going through my codes.Thanks btw

Comment: Anyway, if any query fails from C# code and it reaches the database, the profiler gives you what you actually run against the database. You fix it at SQL level and that adjust your code.

Comment: Could it be that something is wrong is my sql statement?